# R arrow/direction plot from Data.frame

Tags: r, dataframe, coordinates

i am experimenting with different plots. I have a data.frame that looks like this:

```
Date/Time               X       Y
22.06.2016 08:44    12.033  6.440
22.06.2016 08:44    12.062  6.428
22.06.2016 08:45    12.189  6.538
22.06.2016 08:45    12.084  6.455
22.06.2016 08:46    12.069  6.443
22.06.2016 08:46    12.070  6.301
22.06.2016 08:47    12.025  6.298
```

I managed to make a heatmap on a custom background in relation to the density of X/Y coordinates like "many records where made here, but less here".

I would like to experiment with plotting some sort of walkways/trails from x0,y0 to x1,y1 then x1,y1 to x2,y2 and so on (in a perfect world, it should look like a snake on the "ground").

Considering there is only a very small distance between x0y0 and x1y1 this might look a little odd, but I would like to try anyway. I tried something with `arrows()`, but the result did not work at all.

Comment: Any hint? We have to assume that you have tried the example in `?arrows`. Can you please elaborate what went wrong?

Comment: Well, I managed to plot it, but it looks very "mixed up". I was hoping that there might be a more neat way. It now looks like this 
http://imgur.com/a/EujX9, as expected it is quite odd I hope that there are more alternatives than this: `plot(df11$X,df11$Y, main = "arrows(.) and segments(.)")
## draw arrows from point to point :
s <- seq(length(df11$X)-1)  # one shorter than data
arrows(df11$X[s], df11$Y[s], df11$X[s+1], df11$Y[s+1], col = 1:3)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`arrows` worked for me, although it is an odd path.

```
plot(df[,2:3])
arrows(df[-nrow(df), 2], df[-nrow(df), 3], 
    df[-1, 2], df[-1, 3], length=0.1)
```

[image]